# Find Unique Value from a array

Tags: php, arrays, match, magento2

I have a Multidimensional array, I need to find if array have same value of 'brand' attribute then return its id.

I tried via some array functions but it didn't work.
What I Tried:

1)

```
$backwards = array_reverse($attribute);
            echo '<pre>';
            $last_item = NULL;
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($backwards as $current_item) {
                if ($last_item === $current_item[$i]['value']) {
                    echo '<pre>'; print_r($current_item[$i]['value']);
                }
                $last_item = $current_item[$i]['value'];
                echo '<pre>'; print_r($last_item);
                $i++;
            }
```

2)

```
$j = 1;
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($attributeValues as $attributeData) {
                foreach ($attribute as $value) {
                    if($value[$i]['value'] == $value[$j]['value']) {
                        echo '<pre>'; print_r($value); die(); 
                    }
                    $j++;
                }
            }
```

All my solution's not worked, please help.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => brand
                [value] => 54
                [id] => 5251
                [price] => 15000.0000
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => model
                [value] => 1200
                [id] => 5251
                [price] => 15000.0000
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => brand
                [value] => 54
                [id] => 5250
                [price] => 15000.0000
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => model
                [value] => 1200
                [id] => 5250
                [price] => 12000.0000
            )

    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => brand
                [value] => 89
                [id] => 518
                [price] => 100.0000
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => model
                [value] => 12
                [id] => 518
                [price] => 100
            )
    )
```

If `[name]=>brand` and `[name]=>model` value's of first array is same as second array's value then return `[id]`.

Comment: By value's you mean the prices? (and then expected output is id 0?)

Comment: I need to check if value=>54 equals to second array value=> 89 then returns its product id @dWinder

Comment: I am sorry but I still don't understand the logic...

Comment: There are two questions arises, 1.`FOR VALUE 54, there are two product ids, do you want both the product ids ?` 2. `If [name]=>brand and [name]=>model value's of first array is same as second array's value then return [id].`.... **What is/are your questions?** *Your snippet are unclear too*

Comment: @DrakulaPredator 
1. I want to return both product id only.
2. Yes,

Comment: @himani once check my answer as per your requirement.

Comment: Thankyou, you saved me.. @DrakulaPredator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two for loop.

```
$result =[];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $v){
        $result[$v['name']][] = $v['id'];      
    }
}
$result = array_map("array_unique", $result); // to make it unique
print_r($result);
// if you want to check ids for brand
//print_r($result['brand']);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [brand] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5251
            [1] => 5250
            [3] => 518
        )

    [model] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5251
            [1] => 518
        )

)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/GAKuu).

**EDIT**
Then you can group it by name and value of it

```
$result =[];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $v){
        $result[$v['name']."|".$v['value']][] = $v['id'];      
    }
}
$result = array_map("array_unique", $result);
print_r($result);die;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/gaELN).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `foreach` and iterate through the array

```
$res = [];
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
  if($v[0]['name'] == $v[1]['name'])
    $res[$v[0]['name']] = $v[0]['id'];
}
```

If you want to match the index `value` try this

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
  if($v[0]['value'] == $v[1]['value'])
    $res[] = $v[0]['id'];
}
```

[Working example](https://3v4l.org/7GhUC)

Comment: It is not worked.
I want to match 0 index value with 1 index but not worked.

Comment: @RakeshJakhar Are you clear with the question mate?

Comment: @himani  you have mentioned this `If [name]=>brand and [name]=>model value's of first array is same as second array's value then return [id]`, that means in each array there are 2 sub array and you want the id of the matched record with the index `name`

Comment: @himani it wil return the blank because you have `name` index different for each sub array, that means there are no matching